# php curl process into R

Tags: php, r, curl, httr

I got the followig curl process in php:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "www.sample.com";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", "Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; d=0.2"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'auth_tkt=myToken; anotherArg=234');

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Now, I got to translate and perform this in R. I tried with the following, however, I get status 403 back, so I guess the headers or the cookies are not set properly:

```
library(httr)
url <- "www.sample.com"
res <- GET(url, 
           add_headers(`Content-Type` = "application/json",
                       charset="utf-8",
                       Accept = c("application/json", "text/javascript", "*/*"),
                       d="0.2"),
           set_cookies(auth_tkt="myToken", anotherArg="234")
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
httr::GET(
  url = "http://httpbin.org/",
  httr::set_cookies(
    auth_tkt = "myToken",
    anotherArg = 234L
  ),
  httr::content_type("application/json; charset=utf-8"),
  httr::accept("application/json, text/javascript, */*; d=0.2"),
  httr::verbose()
)
```

is *almost* the same thing @Alberto posted except it uses some additional `httr` helper functions and sets the values correctly. I made it `verbose()` so I could show what was sent:

```
-> GET / HTTP/1.1
-> Host: httpbin.org
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.54.0 r-curl/3.2 httr/1.3.1
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Cookie: auth_tkt=myToken;anotherArg=234
-> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
-> Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; d=0.2
```

@Alberto's code ends up sending:

```
-> GET / HTTP/1.1
-> Host: httpbin.org
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.54.0 r-curl/3.2 httr/1.3.1
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Cookie: auth_tkt=myToken;anotherArg=234
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Type: application/json
-> charset: utf-8
-> Accept1: application/json
-> Accept2: text/javascript
-> Accept3: */*
-> d: 0.2
```

which does not fully mimic the PHP example code.

Comment: This is a better fit, but for some reason I still get 403. I need to check my data. Thank you.

Comment: I realize you can't (& should't ever :-) post tokens/etc but is the site super-secret? Some of us have a really bad habit of writing full API wrappers for SO questions and this API you're using could be a good candidate. If it's private I grok why you can't share the domain/URL. Note that it's possible to setup a local copy of https://httpbin.org/ so you can do similar verbose testing without hitting the API directly or leaking tokens to httpbin.

Comment: I have to remain secretive as this is a process of my company. Otherwise I would be glad to share with the community.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the `url` variable on the 3rd line, here's the correct code:

```
library(httr)
url <- "www.sample.com"
res <- GET(url, 
           add_headers(`Content-Type` = "application/json",
                       charset="utf-8",
                       Accept = c("application/json", "text/javascript", "*/*"),
                       d="0.2"),
           set_cookies(auth_tkt="myToken", anotherArg="234")
```

Comment: Hi, thnx, that was a typo indeed, but that is not the problem, still 403 status